# Vertex Labels diferentiating InDegrees from OutDegrees

Tags: labeling

Does anyone know how can I differentiate vertex labels that are InDegrees vs. OutDegrees?
For example, if the graph shows 1 -> 2, or all "names" from column 1 to column 2, how can I have all those in column one appear in a particular color or font, differentiated from those in column 2?

Thanks!

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are asking. Please add the relevant context, and use a small code example to illustrate what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

n = 5;

in = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n]

(* {1, 7, 10, 7, 1} *)

out = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n]

(* {8, 1, 1, 9, 5} *)
```

Distinguish shapes and labels between `in`, `out`, and "both"

```
shapes = Sort[Join[Thread[in -> "Circle"] // Union,
     Thread[out -> "Square"] // Union]] /. {s___, n_ -> _, n_ -> _, 
     e___} :> {s, n -> "Star", e};

labels = Sort[Join[((# -> Style[#, Blue]) & /@ in) // Union,
     ((# -> Style[#, Orange, Italic]) & /@ out) // Union]] /. {s___, n_ -> _, 
     n_ -> _, e___} :> {s, n -> Style[n, Red, Bold], e};

Graph[
 Thread[DirectedEdge[in, out]],
 VertexLabels -> labels,
 VertexShapeFunction -> shapes,
 BaseStyle -> Medium]
```

[image]